# Is it possible to use CSS to resize a container so it's as tall as its background image?

Tags: image, css, background, stretch

I've researched this and only found a JavaScript solution, so wonder if anyone knows if a CSS solution is possible...

Here's a code snippet:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
        This is a small amount of text to appear over the stretched 
        background image, but I want to be able to see the entire image.
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#container 
{
        background: url('images/bigImage.png') no-repeat 0 0;
        background-size: 100%; /* makes the image stretch (vertically and horizontally) to the width of the device, so I've no idea what height the background image will be rendered at.*/
}
```

Is there any CSS I can use so the background image covers the entire div with the entire image being visible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using a static image from your hard drive then why don't you manually type `height: 100px; ` if the height is 100px?

Comment: Because using "background-size: 100%" changes the rendered height of the background image to an unknown value.

Comment: Have you tried `background-size: cover;` ?

Comment: Yes, but then you only see a top strip of the bg image. I need some CSS code that will make the div as tall as the (stretched) bg image.

Comment: ...it's a perfectly legitimate question - esp. as there doesn't seem to be a solution so far.

Comment: @user1617737: The approaches of all the answers are different. This means that the question you asked has many loose ends and each loose end leads to a conclusion and all the posted answers are not accepted by you that means you forgot to mention details. In this case if you can attach a fiddle what you hv got and what is your expected output then we could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As previously stated its not possible to do this with CSS and background-image. Also background-size: cover is not supported by IE8 and lower (And from reading your comments i would assume that you want to have a fluid (scalable) image while maintaining aspect ratio?)

If so you can use a regular img element to achieve this:

```
<style type="text/css">
div#container {
    position    : absolute;
    top         : 0;
    left        : 0;
    overflow    : hidden;
    width       : 100%;
    height      : 100%;
}

div#container img {
    position : absolute;
    width    : 100%;
    top      : 0;
    z-index  : -1;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <img src="http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/18cxbtdr4fexmjpg/original.jpg">
    This is a small amount of text to appear over the stretched
    background image, but I want to be able to see the entire image.
</div>
```

*EDIT* - Heres a jsfiddle to show how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfxar/

Comment: Looks like this is the only way forward. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stretch the div to image size, use

> background-size:cover;

If you want to scale image to div size, use

> background-size:contain;

Comment: Using cover makes the bg image the correct width, but you only see the top 10% of the bg image. How can I dimension the div so that all of its bg image can be seen?

Comment: As far as I know, you need to put a 
`<!DOCTYPE html>`
in your html document to make this work.
Else, as other answers rightly say,
`width:100%;height:100%;` should work.

Comment: ...using 'contain' or 'cover' does not resize the div, which is what I am wanting to do here.

Comment: Wait a sec...So what you exactly want is to resize the div according to the image size?

Comment: Yes, but remember it's an unknown image size because it's an unknown div width.

Comment: I am already using <!DOCTYPE html> , but using height:100% doesn't make the div the same height as its background image.

Comment: I tried your code and many other things...I personally conclude there's no 'CSS' solution.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Maybe the only workaround I can use is to make it a foreground image rather than a background image...

Comment: As you said the correct way to do this is to use a normal img element (see my answer), I wouldn't consider this as a "workaround" though - I think it would also be semantically better to do it this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect the height of a background image in CSS or JS as far as I know, and therefore, you cannot render your DIV to this unknown height.

If you are using PHP though, it's easy as this:

```
<?php
$myURL = "http://i.imgur.com/AiAeQyU.gif";
$myImage = getimagesize($myURL);
?>

<div 
style="
background: url('<?php echo $myURL; ?>') 0 0 no-repeat; 
width: <?php echo $myImage[0] . 'px'; ?>; 
height: <?php echo $myImage[1] . 'px'; ?>
">
<p>Your content</p>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but the image is being stretched to the width of the viewport, so if we don't know the viewport width then we don't know the width/height of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS rules width:100% and height:100% on a div to take up the remaining space of the parent div, if I understand what you are asking. It seems like you're trying to get a background image to stretch to the size of the device, and are already doing this: in general, if you want a DIV to take up the entire space, you can use the percentages in CSS. I believe if you set the background image div in this case to be 100% of the page, as well as the text div, you should fill up the entire page with the background.

Comment: Thanks, but the div isn't to cover the entire page. The div just needs to be the same height as its (stretched) background image.